# how can i find kernel stack overflow “murderer”？

Tags: linux, openwrt

A kernel overflow occured during openwrt startup,this question is probabilistic, about 5%.

I try to disable some linux modules,but kernel overflow still exists,and i can't find "murderer" by the call trace, how can i find it?

Here arm some logs:
From the log, it seems that when entering the SVC exception, el1_da exceptions occurred multiple times.

```
[12-10-18-43-21,666][   45.977765] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]Insufficient stack space to handle exception!
[12-10-18-43-21,666][   45.977769] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]ESR: 0x9600004f -- DABT (current EL)
[12-10-18-43-21,666][   45.979435] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]FAR: 0xffffff800809bfd8
[12-10-18-43-21,666][   45.980065] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]Task stack:     [0xffffff801cb30000..0xffffff801cb34000]
[12-10-18-43-21,666][   45.981056] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]IRQ stack:      [0xffffff8008008000..0xffffff800800c000]
[12-10-18-43-21,666][   45.982046] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]Overflow stack: [0xffffffc03fc6a080..0xffffffc03fc6b080]
[12-10-18-43-21,666][   45.983040] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]CPU: 1 PID: 21400 Comm: sh Tainted: G        W  O      4.19.190-svn1158 #0
[12-10-18-43-21,666][   45.984226] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]Hardware name: MediaTek evb6890v1_64_cpe_nand (DT)
[12-10-18-43-21,666][   45.985152] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]pstate: 40400005 (nZcv daif +PAN -UAO)
[12-10-18-43-21,666][   45.985951] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]pc : free_pcp_prepare+0xc4/0xf0
[12-10-18-43-21,666][   45.986669] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]lr : free_pcp_prepare+0x18/0xf0
[12-10-18-43-21,667][   45.987387] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]sp : ffffff801cb30100
[12-10-18-43-21,667][   45.987995] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]x29: ffffff801cb30100 x28: 0000000000000000 
[12-10-18-43-21,667][   45.988855] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]x27: ffffffc038c33c00 x26: ffffffc038c33c60 
[12-10-18-43-21,667][   45.989716] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]x25: 0000000000000000 x24: ffffffc02041ea00 
[12-10-18-43-21,667][   45.990576] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]x23: 000000009600004f x22: ffffff801cb30370 
[12-10-18-43-21,667][   45.991437] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]x21: ffffff800809bfd8 x20: ffffff800809bfd8 
[12-10-18-43-21,667][   45.992297] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]x19: ffffff800809bfd8 x18: 0000000000000000 
[12-10-18-43-21,667][   45.993157] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]x17: 0000000000000000 x16: 0000000000000000 
[12-10-18-43-21,667][   45.994017] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]x15: 0000000000000000 x14: 0000000000000001 
[12-10-18-43-21,667][   45.994877] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]x13: 0000000000000c50 x12: 0000000000000008 
[12-10-18-43-21,667][   45.995737] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]x11: 0101010101010101 x10: ffffffff7f7f7f7f 
[12-10-18-43-21,667][   45.996597] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]x9 : 0000000000000000 x8 : ffffffc01d05ce00 
[12-10-18-43-21,667][   45.997456] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]x7 : 0000000000000000 x6 : 000000000001159d 
[12-10-18-43-21,667][   45.998315] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]x5 : 0000000000000000 x4 : 00000000fffff000 
[12-10-18-43-21,668][   45.999176] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]x3 : 0000007fc5790000 x2 : ffffff800809bfd8 
[12-10-18-43-21,668][   46.000036] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]x1 : 000000009600004f x0 : a9bf7bfdd6400000 
[12-10-18-43-21,668][   46.000897] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]Kernel panic - not syncing: kernel stack overflow
[12-10-18-43-21,668][   46.001811] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]CPU: 1 PID: 21400 Comm: sh Tainted: G        W  O      4.19.190-svn1158 #0
[12-10-18-43-21,668][   46.002997] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]Hardware name: MediaTek evb6890v1_64_cpe_nand (DT)
[12-10-18-43-21,668][   46.003922] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]Call trace:
[12-10-18-43-21,668][   46.004425] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] dump_backtrace+0x0/0x120
[12-10-18-43-21,668][   46.005078] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] show_stack+0x24/0x30
[12-10-18-43-21,668][   46.005689] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] dump_stack+0x90/0xb8
[12-10-18-43-21,668][   46.006298] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] panic+0x124/0x2a0
[12-10-18-43-21,668][   46.006875] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] nmi_panic+0x60/0x7c
[12-10-18-43-21,668][   46.007473] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] handle_bad_stack+0xfc/0x108
[12-10-18-43-21,668][   46.008159] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] __bad_stack+0xc0/0xc4
[12-10-18-43-21,668][   46.008778] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] free_pcp_prepare+0xc4/0xf0
[12-10-18-43-21,668][   46.009453] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] free_unref_page+0x2c/0x88
[12-10-18-43-21,669][   46.010117] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] __free_pages+0x40/0x5c
[12-10-18-43-21,669][   46.010749] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] __do_kernel_fault+0x78/0x100
[12-10-18-43-21,669][   46.011444] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] do_page_fault+0x3fc/0x41c
[12-10-18-43-21,669][   46.012107] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] do_mem_abort+0x6c/0x100
[12-10-18-43-21,669][   46.012749] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] el1_da+0x1c/0xac
[12-10-18-43-21,761][   46.076779] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] free_pcp_prepare+0xc4/0xf0
[12-10-18-43-21,761][   46.077453] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] free_unref_page+0x2c/0x88
[12-10-18-43-21,762][   46.078117] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] __free_pages+0x40/0x5c
[12-10-18-43-21,762][   46.078748] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] __do_kernel_fault+0x78/0x100
[12-10-18-43-21,762][   46.079444] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] do_translation_fault+0x94/0x98
[12-10-18-43-21,763][   46.080162] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] do_mem_abort+0x6c/0x100
[12-10-18-43-21,763][   46.080803] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] el1_da+0x1c/0xac
[12-10-18-43-21,763][   46.081369] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] __slab_free.isra.15+0x44/0x230
[12-10-18-43-21,764][   46.082088] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] kmem_cache_free+0x1a0/0x214
[12-10-18-43-21,764][   46.082774] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] putname+0x6c/0x70
[12-10-18-43-21,765][   46.083351] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] open_exec+0x4c/0x5c
[12-10-18-43-21,765][   46.083951] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] load_elf_binary+0x234/0x1548
[12-10-18-43-21,765][   46.084647] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] search_binary_handler+0x184/0x23c
[12-10-18-43-21,766][   46.085397] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] __do_execve_file.isra.13+0x40c/0x648
[12-10-18-43-21,766][   46.086181] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] do_execve+0x48/0x58
[12-10-18-43-21,767][   46.086779] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] __arm64_sys_execve+0x34/0x48
[12-10-18-43-21,767][   46.087476] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] el0_svc_common.constprop.0+0x94/0x114
[12-10-18-43-21,767][   46.088270] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] el0_svc_handler+0x44/0x78
[12-10-18-43-21,768][   46.088934] <1>-(1)[21400:sh] el0_svc+0x8/0xc
[12-10-18-43-21,768][   46.089491] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
[12-10-18-43-21,771][   46.090178] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]Kernel Offset: disabled
[12-10-18-43-21,783][   46.090810] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]CPU features: 0x00000004,22002238
[12-10-18-43-21,786][   46.091549] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]Memory Limit: none
[12-10-18-43-21,805][   46.125502] <1>-(1)[21400:sh]Rebooting in 3 seconds..
```

Comment: Have you written any of this code? If not, it's not a programming question per se and would be better posted to [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). Stack Overflow is for help writing and debugging your own code.

Comment: of course,i do.I think there is a problem with a driver that I developed by myself, but I don't know which one it is, so I need help with how to find it.

Comment: Everything above open_exec is cleanup, so it happened while looking up or loading an ELF binary. There is a bug either in the binary or the path name passed to the kernel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.